# phpmyadmin server pb importing the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I made a website on localhost using Wordpress on the Wamp server. Locally the website works fine but every time I try to upload the database on *1and1* hosting or on *godadddy* hosting I get the same error `1044 did not grant user privilege`. How do I fix this issue?

I'm using root as the user locally .I tried to upload db on server and granted privilege to user@%. Saw the same post but no answer

Comment: goto your localhost/phpmyadmin  and if you are not using the root user grant  the required permission to the user you are using

Comment: I m using the root user .Do you think that is the pb ?

Comment: you won't have the user `root` on a shared hosting such as godaddy or 1and1

Comment: if 1and1, you can get the database credentials from the database page, not phpadmin page, then update those in `wp-config.php`

Comment: fix the pb already found it on my own .Thx but your help was not helpfeul .This has nothing to do with user root.